# WebClient.FileDownlOad GIVIn error that the file a is accessed by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, system.net

I am trying to download a file using webclient method `DownloadFile` But its giving me error that

```
 The process cannot access the file '...\d915877c-cb7c-4eeb-97d8-41d49b75aa27.docx' because it is being used by another process.
```

But when I open the file by clicking it, it opening.

There are same question requesting same info but none are accepted answers.

any help will be appreciated

It may be oS that is not letting file go. Whatever it is but after searching a lot I am unable to find solution

Here is the code to create a file

```
  Document d = new Document();
  d.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Invoice\" + iname + ".docx"));
```

I am using aspose word `dll`

and following way I am accessing it

```
 using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.DownloadFile(Server.MapPath("invoice/" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + ".docx"),Server.MapPath("invoice/" +Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + ".docx"));
            client.Dispose();
        }
```

and BTW its giving same error even to files that are not creaated using code.

Comment: Seems that file is readonly. Check the attribute of the file. Also how this file is getting created. By code? Provide more detail about the question.

Comment: I checked file is NOT readonly. and am able to edit it. and I am creating through aspose word api

Comment: close the document after saving

Comment: @Isuru the object does not have either close or dispose method, so I am assigning the object value `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a different path where to save the download file which is different from the download source path. If you want to replace the file do it after disposing the webclient by using `File.replace()` method.

```
string downloadPath = "Your download path";      
string destinationPath = "the path where the file should be saved";`//this should be different from "download path"                   
 File.Download(downloadPath,destinationPath);
```

Comment: the object does not have either close or dispose method, so I am assigning the object value null

Comment: and BTW its giving same error even to files that are not creaated using code.

Comment: Ok I get your problem. You are trying to download the file to the same location as the download source path.   `client.DownloadFile(Server.MapPath("invoice/" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + ".docx"),""Differentpath"))`;

Comment: `string downloadPath = "Your download path";`
`string destinationPath = "the path where the file should be saved";` //this should be different from "download path"
`File.Download(downloadPath,destinationPath);`